# Typescript: Convert a string array into string literal

Tags: typescript

I want to convert list of currency codes into a string literal. It has a feature of setting const assertions to make string literals. [Typescript 3.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/) . The following code works

```
let ccs = <const>['INR', 'USD']
type CurrencyCode = typeof ccs[number]
let cc: CurrencyCode = 'PKR'
```

It throws the error `Type '"PKR"' is not assignable to type '"INR" | "USD"'`

But the following code does not throw any error. Why is it so? What changes should I make to ensure that the output of a function can be converted into a string literal?

```
function getCurrencyCodes() {
  return ['INR', 'USD']
}

let val: string[] = getCurrencyCodes()
let ccs = <const>[...val]
type CurrencyCode = typeof ccs[number]
let cc: CurrencyCode = 'PKR'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is not runtime language.

Second code does not work since you are using function witch will be evaluated in run time.

When using const typescript can say exact type. Not with functions

```
function getCurrencyCodes(): ['INR', 'USD'] {
  return ['INR', 'USD'];
}

const val = getCurrencyCodes();
const ccs = [...val];
type CurrencyCode = typeof ccs[number];
const cc: CurrencyCode = 'PKR'; // here you got error
```

since function type is const can be narrow by typescript
if you are returning string[] typescript can not narrow exact literal type

Comment: Or `function getCurrencyCodes() {
  return ['INR', 'USD'] as const;
}`

Comment: in what typescript version you can do this?

Comment: 3.4 just released, not on the playground yet, need to npm install it

Comment: yeah i see, nice